# Risks of using free proxy and VPN services

Tags: vpn, proxy

There are millions of people that are daily using free **Proxy** and/or free **VPN** service for different purposes, some of these services are famous and have many users.

What are the risks when using a free service since these service providers can view, tamper, record, and log all your traffic?

What are the chances and the possibility of using this *Data* for other purposes like advertising?

Comment: There have been no changes to the content of the question, so there is no reason to open it. And please do not radically change the question. Ask a new one.

Comment: @schroeder you mentioned the other time that I cannot change the question that has already answers.

Comment: Right. So if you want to ask a different question, post a ***new*** question. Don't change this one.

Comment: @schroeder if I ask a new question and in the meantime, this question exist then it will be a duplicate or should I delete this question an ask a new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... other than the fact that the proxy can view, record, and log all your traffic?

I don't consider this a small risk already since the ability to view the traffic also includes the ability to steal credentials, session cookies etc. But it gets worse: the proxy can actually modify the traffic.

If you use only HTTPS and don't install some certificate which allows the proxy to intercept this traffic then this is probably less a problem since HTTPS protects against traffic modification (i.e. at worst data transfer will fail). But if you only use a little bit of plain HTTP (which is very likely) then the proxy might  modify these - for example injecting ads, modifying downloads in-place so that they are infected, redirecting you to some phishing sites which look like real sites (but are not) where you enter your credentials ...

At the end you should ask yourself what the business model for the operator of the proxy is. To run such a proxy money and time are needed and the better the proxy is (bandwidth, speed...) the more money is needed. Since only few have money to throw away there is usually some downside - if you don't pay you are the product.